# Validate diff patch prior to applying it

Tags: php, diff, patch, auto-update

I'm looking for a diff library that is portable ( No Pear, no php non-widely supported extensions -- like xdiff ) that allow me to do file patch for an update mechanism. The diff file I use are using the **unified** format.

I've found class.simplediff.php witch is really nice, ( even if it doesn't support file out of the box, it's just a matter of loading a file in a string )

But the problem is that I can't find a way to validate if all replacement are able to be processed successfully or not.

Do you know a library that allow to validate the diff patching prior to applying it, or do you have a clue on how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've translated the patch.c code to PHP:

https://gist.github.com/1707075

The patch.c code itself is kind of messy, so is the PHP code. The hunk validation works, but it's not as "safe" as I would need -- that's why it's not the answer I'm looking for, but maybe it will help someone else.

Edit:

I've coded something. I'm not yet sure if it's 100% reliable, but the results so far are really good in term of "validating in read only to ensure that the patch will be applied with success": https://github.com/idealtech/UnifiedDiffPatcher

Hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way you can tell whether the patch works -- logically, that is. However if your patch source is considered "safe" you might be able to check whether it is at least valid syntax by doing the following:

1. [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) the file to be patched
2. [apply](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) patch
3. attempt to execute file using PHP cli (e.g. `php file.php`)

If  step 3 does not throw an fatal exception, then the patch likely resulted in valid PHP syntax.

You would not want to do this if the source of the patch is unsafe given that executing arbitrary PHP could result in someone taking control of your machine.

Comment: Well, when using the unix patch command, you may have "Hunk failed" error. That's what I want to check ... Because if a replacement can't be made, usually it doesn't break the code syntactically speaking.